# AttributeError when trying to use the append function for DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append, series, attributeerror

Im trying to add a Series to my DataFrame with the append funtion. I'm not trying to permanently change the DataFrame, this is just for study purposes. I get a traceback that 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'.

**My DataFrame:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Population': [35.467, 63.951, 80.94, 60.665, 127.061, 64.511, 318.523],
    'GDP': [
        1785387,
        2833687,
        3874437,
        2167744,
        4602367,
        2950039,
        17348075
    ],
    'Surface Area': [
        9984670,
        640679,
        357114,
        301336,
        377930,
        242495,
        9525067
    ],
    'HDI': [
        0.913,
        0.888,
        0.916,
        0.873,
        0.891,
        0.907,
        0.915
    ],
    'Continent': [
        'America',
        'Europe',
        'Europe',
        'Europe',
        'Asia',
        'Europe',
        'America'
    ]
}, columns=['Population', 'GDP', 'Surface Area', 'HDI', 'Continent'])
```

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2dO5.png)

**What im trying to add:**

```
df.append(pd.Series({
    'Population': 3,
    'GDP': 5
}, name='China'))
```

**The Attribute Error:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9724\2859580344.py in ?()
----> 1 df.append(pd.Series({
      2     'Population': 3.,
      3     'GDP': 5
      4 }, name='China'))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ?(self, name)
   5985             and name not in self._accessors
   5986             and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5987         ):
   5988             return self[name]
-> 5989         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I already tried to update pandas, but its running on the newest version. I closed Vscode and ran all again. Nothing has changed.

**What I'm expecting:**

[Updated DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9ZR.png)